# Change script for radio buttons to regular buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, radio-button

So I have this script that I've been using that works nicely for an my purposes but it is built with radio buttons, and I've been asked to do another project with it, but my boss would like the buttons to now be regular, non-radio buttons.

Here is the code I've been using so far. It's a lot harder to change over radio-button code to regular button code than I thought! Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#TFholder{
   background-image:url('truefalse.png');
   height:84px;
   width:576px;
}

button{
    height:84px; 
    width:280px; 
    color:white; 
    background-color:black;      
    margin-top:50px; 
    text-align:center; 
    line-height:10px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;}

button a{
    display:block;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:20px 40px;}
</style>  

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onCheck() {
if (document.getElementById('check1').checked) {
    document.getElementById('truebox').style.display = 'block';

    }
else document.getElementById('falsebox').style.display = 'block';

    }
</script>
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onCheck();" name="check" id="check1"><br> 
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:onCheck();" name="check" id="check2"><br>
<div id="TFholder">
  <div id="truebox" style="display:none">
    <button type="button">CONTINUE!!!</a></div>
  </div>

  <div id="falsebox" style="display:none">
     <button type="button">SECOND BUTTON!!!</a></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do? Radio buttons serve a different purpose.

Comment: Basically it's a true/false. If you click one image, an image pops up that either says 'correct' or 'incorrect' on it. The message depends on which button you click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change HTML part to:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="javascript:b1();"/><br />
<br />
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" onclick="javascript:b2();"/><br>
```

change Script part to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function b1() {
        document.getElementById('truebox').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function b2() {
        document.getElementById('falsebox').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: With this you can get the effect of the radio buttons, the last selected will be hidden when click a new button, [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/cigolayo/11/edit?html,output). Also you can add more buttons and put the target that you want (truebox or falsebox).